# How do I make this sound loop?

Tags: java, audio, javasound, stack-overflow

I am trying to loop the sound in this code. In the finally block of the main try and catch I do this :

```
    if (loop) {
        auline.flush();
        run();
    } else {
        ended=true;
        auline.drain();
        auline.close();
    }
```

but it causes a stackoverflow. How can I safely loop this sound without creating a new instance of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `run` from within `run`, this will eventually fill up the call stack & result in your stack overflow exception

Now, the question is, how do you overcome it?

You need to loop within the run method.  The best way I can think of is to have a "exit" trigger in the run method

```
public void run() {
    while(loop) {
        //...play sound
    }
}
```

You could the use `stop` method to also trigger the `loop` flag

Comment: See also [`Clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Clip.html#loop%28int%29) as shown in the [Java Sound info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info).